# Android SQLQuery for UPDATE

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

This is my table that was created:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String insertNewFormDetails = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                                                            + NAME + " text not null, "
                                                            + SCHOOL + " text not null, "
                                                            + CURRENTDATE + " text not null, "
                                                            + FORMTYPE + " text not null);";
    // Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.
    db.execSQL(insertNewFormDetails);
}
```

so now there's this primary key that's having autoincrement. How do I actually get the content of that column?

What I'm doing now for the `UPDATE` query.

```
DBAddForm dbOpener2 = new DBAddForm(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase2 = dbOpener2.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "FormDetails";
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpener2.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
                contentValues2.put("school",school);
                sqliteDatabase2.update("FormDetails", contentValues2, cursor.getString(0) + " = " +primaryKey , null);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

However, what it does now is to update all the rows in the first column. I only wanted it to update the row when it equals to the `primaryKey`. Advise please? Thanks! I got really confused with all the trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! My answer adjusted with suggestions. It works now.

```
DBAddForm dbOpener2 = new DBAddForm(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase2 = dbOpener2.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT _id FROM " + DBAddForm.TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpener2.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
                contentValues2.put("SCHOOL",school);
                contentValues2.put("NAME", name);
                //update query
                sqliteDatabase2.update("FormDetails", contentValues2, "_id" +  " = " + primaryKey  , null);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    sqliteDatabase2.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you should use  `SCHOOL` instead of `"school"`. And `TABLE_NAME` intead of `"FormDetails"`.Youre looking for trouble having hardcoded strings.

Then, print or log the values of `Cursor.getString(0)` and `primaryKey`. You may then be able to debug the problem yourself

Comment: really? i thought it's done this way from the examples I found online. Instead of hardcoded what else can I do?

Comment: You're correct in your CREATE because these strings are not hard coded. But you need to change your SELECT and UPDATE. Hardcoded strings lead to trouble because you need to ensure that they are consistent throughout your code

Comment: Btw, which online examples are you following?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Remove `"FormDetails"` and replace it by `TABLE_NAME`.

Then Remove `school` and replace it by `SCHOOL`.

The `select` query returns all the records. I think the `Cursor.getString(0)` always getting the first value. And also check whether you updating the `primary key` correctly by printing it.

Instead of `do While` Loop try `for` Loop

```
for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
{
//Now check your cursor value with the primary key. It may work
Use this cursor.getString(i)
}
```